# Windows c++ service faulting on ucrtbase.dll when starting

Tags: windows, dll, service, fault

So I've been developing this program for a while now... Its meant to act as an asset manager (and potentially more in the future) for our IT team. I have 2 services which we'll refer to as "Manager" and "IAM" for right now. The "Manager" does all things managerial for all services (currently only the inventory asset manager known as "IAM") such as automatic updates, etc., while the asset manager does its job.

Anyways, its been working great for a while now. Recently I implemented an automatic updating feature (actually still needing to be tested and likely debugged). While doing this, I needed to get my naming consistent (for example, renaming my service from "Updater" and "CppWindowsService" to the software's actual name).

Before this, it had been working great! Started, stopped, installed, and uninstalled with no hiccups. I change the name for everything, and make sure it all compiles ok. Looks good. Install works great for both "Manager" and "IAM" now, but as soon as I try to start it, I get:

> StartService failed (1053)

Also, when I try to start it from services.msc, then I get the following error message:

> Windows could not start the  service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1053:  The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

The strange thing about this though is that it doesn't wait for any sort of timeout.  It just instantly spits out the message.  That message comes from the code called from my wmain() (windows entry point.  `main()` otherwise.) function.

```
if (!StartService(
        schService,  // handle to service 
        0,           // number of arguments 
        NULL))      // no arguments 
    {
        printf("StartService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }
    else printf("Service start pending...\n");
```

In Windows Event Log, I get an application error containing the following details after fault.

> Faulting application name: InITManager.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x59e11e44
>
> Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.15063.674, time stamp: 0x8ac9f9d4
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000409
>
> Fault offset: 0x000000000007350e
>
> Faulting process id: 0x3008
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d346915918e17d
>
> Faulting application path: 
>   C:\Users\collin.walker\Desktop\InITService\C++\x64\Release\Manager.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
>
> Report Id: 7fcbdcc4-be8e-476a-960f-4fa1fb21f892
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Other info:  ucrtbase.dll is used by Visual Studio and is associated with the Release build, where as ucrtbased.dll is associated with the debugger build.  I am building in Release mode.

Now, I've already been told the issue isn't my code, but if anyone feels as though they need to see it, I will include it then.  Its very straightforward c++ winapi stuff though.

If anyone has any further suggestions on how to troubleshoot this, please let me know, and thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with ucrtbase.dll, it is merely the bearer of the bad news.  0xc0000409 is a nasty kind of exception, it is raised when your code corrupts a stack frame.  Most typically a char[] local variable in which you copy too many char.  Common mishap, getting the code to run reliably in production on another machine is the other 90% of the project.  Run it with a debugger attached to get a break when it happens.

Comment: @HansPassant, `ucrtbase + 7350e` is the int 0x29 instruction in the CRT's [`abort`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/abort) function. This is the [`__fastfail` intrinsic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/fastfail) for a [`KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check---bug-check-0x139-kernel-security-check-failure) with the code `FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT` (7). The interrupt gets serviced by `KiRaiseSecurityCheckFailure`, which raises `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN` (0xC0000409).

Comment: Awesome, that helps a ton!  Thank you!  I appreciate all the help! (not /s)

Comment: @eryksun I am interested in how you were able to discern that information (its very useful) I created a separate post to learn how to do what you did here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251391/how-can-i-find-the-code-executed-at-the-specified-offset-in-ucrtbase-dll and would love to hear from you!

Comment: It's unfortunate @eryksun never responded back -- I need to know this info, too.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of forgot about this post during my troubleshooting... Anyways, I figured it out.  Comments above were spot on!

For me the buffer overflow came from me changing my service names, which also changed the program directory names.  The error was happening when I was initializing my logging object in my service's constructor.  I only have like 2 lines of code in the constructor, so I totally forgot to look there.  Changed the hardcoded directory location where the log was being created, and it all started working great!  Thanks guys for the helpful info!